# Eagle Freeware - definition of 'signal layers'

Tags: eaglecad, freeware, layers

According the the Cadsoft website, Eagle Freeware supports '2 signal layers'.  Am I right that Cadsoft includes power and ground layers in their definition of 'signal layers'?

In other words, am I right that Eagle Freeware doesn't support 2 signal layers, a ground layer and a power layer?

Comment: "am I right that Eagle Freeware doesn't support 2 signal layers, a ground layer and a power layer?" Yes, you are right. Freeware Eagle does *not* support 2 signals layers, power and ground. It only gives two layers, and doesn't differentiate what you put on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The freeware version allows two layers, but what you use them for is up to you.

Obviously with only two layers, you have to mix power, ground and signal to some extent within those layers.

For projects requiring more than two layers, where having separate power and ground layers is applicable, you will want to consider paid versions instead.

Answer (score 1):

You get two layers, top and bottom, with the freeware. Defining a layer as 'ground', 'power', 'signal' is irrelevant.